# Way to find modern site is public or private using CSOM

Tags: sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-online, csom, sharepoint-rest-api

I'm trying to get if the site is private or public.

As per my research if its a communication site default it is a private site.
If its a team site with no group then its a private site.
If its a Classic Team Site then its a Private Site.

If the site is Modern Team Site then it may be public or private. How can I differentiate them using CSOM. In graph we have the property called Visibility of a group under "/groups" endpoint.

How can I get the site is private or public using CSOM. Is there any property or any fields that denote the visibility of the site?